# Transfer php session to a new window opened with window.open in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day all, I am rendering an online exam by opening a new window via javascript, but I have tried closing the current window while opening the new window, all to no avail, hence, I resolved to transfer the phpsession cookie from the current window to the new window so that the phpsession cookie will only be in the newly opened window and be deleted from the current window. I hope I'm clear enough with my illustration. I'm willing to explain further if needed.
Here's my code for opening a new window which works.

```
$(function() {
  var href = $("#openWindow").attr('href');
  var windowOpened = false;

  var h = 685,
  w = 1085;

  if ($(this).hasClass('largew'))
    w = 1155;

  $("#openWindow").click(function(){
  if (windowOpened == false) {
    window.open(href, '', "height=" + h + ",width=" + w + ",scrollbars=yes");
    windowOpened = true;
  } else {
      alert("You have an exam session running already!!");
  }

    return false;
  });
 }
 );
```

From my code, I already check whether the new window is opened already, and the phpsession id is in the new window, but still exists in the current window from which I executed window.open, all I want is to remove the phpsession cookie from the current window from which I executed window.open.
I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: As far as I know a cookie is not bound to a window... it is bound to a domain.